# Modal in modal - close button closes both modals

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I used this code, to create a modal in a modal
http://jsfiddle.net/4w34e4q6/

Open first modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="one">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#two">Open second modal</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
   </div>
</div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

<div class="modal fade" id="two">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

It comes with a closebutton in the second modal and it's supposed to close only that modal and not the first, however it closes both modals.

Is there something I need to add to this code, or the one in js?

Thanks!

Comment: It appears to work as expected here - http://jsfiddle.net/unto9g0L/

Comment: I updated your fiddle to use jquery and bootstrap and then hit run and it worked fine.

Comment: As a heads-up, Bootstrap advises against having two modals at the same time: *"Overlapping modals not supported: Be sure not to open a modal while another is still visible. Showing more than one modal at a time requires custom code."* http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's likely intended behaviour, however to get round it you could try:

```
data-dismiss="two"
```

Calling the ID of the object. If that doesn't work you may have to use your own js method:

```
Onclick="$('#two').hide();"
```

Or similar